# Two different length vector product

Tags: r

If I have two vector with different length.

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3)
b <- c(4, 5)
```

I want each element of b multiply a, so I can obtain a 3 by 2 matrix.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use `outer` for this:

```
outer(a, b)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    4    5
## [2,]    8   10
## [3,]   12   15
```

You could also use `sapply`, like this:

```
sapply(a, "*", b)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    4    8   12
## [2,]    5   10   15
```